# validation of email, with last characters

Tags: php, regex, email

I am having problem in validating email address with regular expression.The code is seems to works fine until user put some long characters separated by(.dot) at end.Code is

```
if(preg_match('~^\b[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-z]{2,4}+\b$~',$_POST["email"]))

{
    $valid ="valid";
}
else
{
    $valid ="invalid";
}
```

Problem comes when user put something like ksdlk@gll.lik.ij.lio.lk.gr it returns "valid". How to deal with last characters, that would only allow 4,5 characters from @ like ".com"or ".co.uk".

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can have a look at this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

Comment: What's wrong with `ksdlk@gll.lik.ij.lio.lk.gr`?

Comment: http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/362536

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.gr

Comment: Please don't reinvent the wheel badly and use the [Filter](http://php.net/filter) extension to validate email addresses.

Comment: there is no wrong in  ksdlk@gll.lik.ij.lio.lk.gr some mail id's contains subdomains also like subdomain.maindomai.in

Comment: @Krishna Oh...I was not aware of that..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this

```
if(filter_var('email@example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))return TRUE;
else return FALSE;
```